# Read variables from searched pattern and replace the pattern with different one using read variables

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I want to replace a pattern in text file and read variables `x` and `y` from the pattern to insert them into the pattern I will be replacing with.

I want to replace every occurrence of:

```
Array<x, y> someArray;
```

With the following:

```
Array<> someArray(x, y);
```

So, for example this line:

```
Array<3, 4> someArray;
```

Will be replaced with:

```
Array<> someArray(3, 4);
```

How do I achieve that using awk or sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **`sed`**:

```
sed -E 's/^(Array)<([^>]+)>( someArray)/\1<>\3(\2)/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat r.sh
awk '
BEGIN {
    b = "[ \t]+"         # blank
    i = "[_a-zA-Z0-9]+"  # identifier: should match x, 1 and so on
}
{
    parse()
    if (OK)
        printf "Array<> %s(%s, %s);\n", name, x, y
    else
        print $0
}
function parse() {
    l = $0; OK = 1
    n("Array")
    n("<")
    n(i); x = P
    n(",")
    n(i); y = P
    n(">")
    n(i); name = P
}
function n(p) {
    if (!OK) return
    n1(b); OK = 1 # skip blank
    return n1(p)
}
function n1(p) {
    p = "^" p
    if (match(l, p)) P = n0()
    else OK = 0
}
function n0(   s) {
    s = substr(l, 1, RLENGTH)
    l = substr(l, RLENGTH + 1)
    return s
}
' "$@"
```

Usage

```
$ sh r.sh file
Array<> someArray(x, y);
Array<> someArray(3, 4);
```